# how to solve null exception for var type variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

var Ongoing_List = _objApi.OngingList(user_id).ToList();

i have one function OngoingList(). when it return data it work approprite but when return then then var OngoingList return can not handle null exception. how to solve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

check if it is not null and its count is greater than zero (it have values) as following

```
if(Ongoing_List != null && Ongoing_List.Count()>0){
     //do your job
}else{
     //don't do any thing with it here
}
```

also you may add try-catch block, which will throw an exception if something occurs as following

```
try{
    if(Ongoing_List != null && Ongoing_List.Count()>0){
         //do your job
    }else{
         //don't do any thing with it here
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    //you can handle the error, maybe print it to a log file or something else
}
```

best regards